# show youtube playlist titles on web page

Tags: youtube

Using iframe a youtube playlist embed displays the first video
[playlist opens with this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0etRk.png)

I want the view to open like this

[This is my preferred default view (I would really like to open with titles, not thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foE5a.png)

Comment: It seems is not possible (*directly*) through YouTube Iframe API - as it seems you're using in your screenshots. see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27951400/4092887.

Comment: Here are some other questions and answers that might help, you have to use another approach, though. [question # 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35570567/4092887), [question # 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15056634/4092887), [question # 3 and check the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57459015/4092887).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is not possible using YouTube Data API.

You'll have to use YouTube Data API for retrieve the videos from a given playlist, then, use custom code `HTML, CSS, javascript, etc`, for create a similar result as you need.